# How to escape white space in nmake

Tags: nmake

I´m trying to use nmake call MSTest

```
TEST="%VS90COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\MSTest.exe"
test:
  $(TEST) /testcontainer:Test.dll
```

When i run nmake i got:

```
$ nmake test
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

Double quote doesn´t work right

**EDIT:**

Thanks "Eric Melski".
I created something like:

```
TEST_="%VS90COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\MSTest.exe" 
TEST="$(TEST_)" /nologo /noresults

test: 
  $(TEST) /testcontainer:Test.dll
```

Comment: Use a `CARET (^)` to escape white space

Comment: I want to use "%VS90COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\MSTest.exe" not "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe". Caret only work in the second option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put double quotes around the usage of `$(TEST)` as well:

```
TEST="%VS90COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\MSTest.exe"
test:
  "$(TEST)" /testcontainer:Test.dll
```

Works with nmake 7 and 8.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem before. Well, you can escape the white space in CMD with a '\' when you type manually, while the command is auto generated in this case. So my way is to use a another path without white space in it. Make sure you share your way if you find a better one.