# NMake macro definition on CLI which contains a space

Tags: escaping, nmake

I have a Makefile which requires an output path to be set.

Right now I use

```
nmake /nologo /f Makefile outdir=%OUTDIR% LANGID=%1 ISO=%2
```

but this doesn't work if the output path contains spaces (%OUTPUT% does not contain quotes).

Additionally there seems to be a bug in the command line argument parser of nmake, so that

```
nmake /nologo /f Makefile outdir="%OUTDIR%" LANGID=%1 ISO=%2
```

and

```
nmake /nologo /f Makefile "outdir=%OUTDIR%" LANGID=%1 ISO=%2
```

also don't work. In these cases `outdir` will be set to `[outdir]" LANGID=[VALUE1] ISO=[VALUE2]` (values I provided on cli in brackets) and `LANGID` and `ISO` are not recognized at all.

Right now I'm using the (ugly) workaround (note that there is only on doublequote)

```
nmake /nologo /f Makefile LANGID=%1 ISO=%2 outdir="%OUTDIR%
```

however, this only works if only one command line argument has spaces.

How to pass paths to nmake properly so that those also work in case they have a space inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any particular problem with spaces when calling NMAKE. There is, however, a problem with calling NMAKE with directory paths that end in a backslash, as this acts as an escape character!

I have tried with this example Makefile:

```
!MESSAGE Makeflags=$(MAKEFLAGS)
!MESSAGE OUTDIR=$(OUTDIR) LANGID=$(LANGID) ISO=$(ISO)
OD=$(OUTDIR)
LI=$(LANGID)
IS=$(ISO)

# To be a valid makefile it must have some rules to perform
all:
    @echo;OUTDIR=$(OUTDIR) LANGID=$(LANGID) ISO=$(ISO)
    @echo;OUTDIR=$(OD)     LANGID=$(LI)     ISO=$(IS)
```

When run from the command prompt we get:

```
C:\Users\Brian>nmake /NOLOGO  "OUTDIR=C:\Program Files\\" "LANGID=C Sharp" "ISO=ISO 8601"
Makeflags=L
OUTDIR=C:\Program Files\ LANGID=C Sharp ISO=ISO 8601
OUTDIR=C:\Program Files\ LANGID=C Sharp ISO=ISO 8601
OUTDIR=C:\Program Files\ LANGID=C Sharp ISO=ISO 8601
```

You can see the spaces have been transferred to the macro values correctly. However, you can also see the problem with the trailing backslash in the path name. If I do not escape this properly there will be an error:

```
C:\Users\Brian>nmake /NOLOGO  "OUTDIR=C:\Program Files\" "LANGID=C Sharp" "ISO=I
SO 8601"
NMAKE : fatal error U1001: Syntaxfehler: ungueltiges Zeichen ' ' in Makro
Stop.
```

So any batch file that calls NMAKE must be carefully written to protect against this specific case.

For completeness; although they do not address your question, they may be useful references:

- SO Question: [How to escape white space in nmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551480/how-to-escape-white-space-in-nmake)
- The role of special characters and escape characters in NMAKE is covered in the [manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa448720.aspx).